# .NET Core 3.1 debugger doesn't show the exact row in code where problem occurs

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core

I have a problem with .NET Core 3.1 when I debug and there is a problem in the code. Normally the debugger will show the EXACT row where the problem occurs but now it only opens a "ExceptionDispatcherInfo.cs" file and shows some information that
***"System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"***

So I don't know where/on what row this exactly happens. How can I change so the debugger shows the exact row. To mention is that it has always done this with .NET Core 3.1 since I started with this 1 week ago.

**I have tried this:**

1. I have in Configuration Manager put: Configuration, Debug
2. Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General. I have enabled/disabled the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" with no difference.
3. In the project properties=>Advanced=>Debugging information. I changed mine to full.

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Please, do not post code as images. No one can reproduce it, unfortunately

Comment: @Pavel I removed the code image then.

Comment: https://roslyn-analyzers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-debug.html

Comment: @Hans Inthe debug tab I can't find `Start action` or `Start options`. Then `Tools->Extensions and Updates` doesn't exist in VS Pro 2019? Not even `Tools->Extensions`